# Ajax data post will not succeed even though php file returns JSON array

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

So I have a function. It sends a number to data.php and the file returns (with json encoding):

```
[{"sprint":"541"},{"sprint":"544"},{"sprint":"547"},{"sprint":"550"},{"sprint":"602"}]
```

The function is:

```
function post_num(val){

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "data.php",
        data:{
            number:val
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            alert("test");
        }
    });
}
```

The ajax won't succeed (it wont alert "test") and I'm not really sure why. Can't see where the error is.

data.php:

```
$number = @$_POST['number'];

$query = mysql_query("........");
$json = array();

while($array = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

$num= $array['Col_number'];

$object = array(
    'Number' => "$num"
);
array_push($json, $object);

}

$jsonstring = json_encode($json);
echo $jsonstring;
```

Comment: What is the error and what's the code in `data.php`?

Comment: It wont alert "test". Updated question @FernandoGallegoFernández

Comment: @Fernando, include into ajax also `error` callback like `success`. It accepts an error as first argument. So you can `console.log(error.statusText)` or `alert(error.statusText)` in the error callback

Comment: **TIP:** When developing websites, always work with the developer tools open (F12) and avoid `alert` in favour of `console.log`. You can even `console.log(data)` and iterate the data with your mouse manually. Way better than a text alert. Even better: `console.log(arguments)`.